# How to only display sql record once during while statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a `while` statement to display a image of an artist in my database. At the moment, it displays the same image multiple times rather than once. How can I make it so the image is shown once and not multiple times?

Here`s my code :

```
<?
while ($feed = mysql_fetch_object($query)) { ?>
<?
    if ($count == '4') {
        $count = 0; ?>

        <div class="blog_item">
        <div class="preview_wrapper">
        <div class="featured_image_full">

<?
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Artists` WHERE `Genre1` = '$usr->Genre1' OR `Genre2` = '$usr->Genre1' OR `Genre3` = '$usr->Genre1' OR `Genre1` = '$usr->Genre2' OR `Genre2` = '$usr->Genre2' OR `Genre3` = '$usr->Genre2' OR `Genre1` = '$usr->Genre3' OR `Genre2` = '$usr->Genre3' OR `Genre3` = '$usr->Genre3' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");

        while ($art = mysql_fetch_object($query1)) { ?>
            <img src="<? echo $art->image; ?>">
        <? } ?>
```

Comment: are you sure that's your actual code, because based on the limit that should be impossible. unless the above is inside another loop?

Comment: You should never use `ORDER BY RAND()`, it's really slow.

Comment: Hi, sorry didn't realize I didnt post the above code. It is inside another loop. Basically it is an activity feed that shows the users recent activity, however every 4 items I want it to display a artist that they may be interested in, just never the same one twice!

Shall i post my above code as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you have multiple images of that artist in your database. Try to **remove the redundancy from your database.** Even then if you wish to execute your `while` loop once
use `break`:

```
while ( $art = mysql_fetch_object ( $query1 ) )
{
?>

<img src ="<?echo $art->image;?>">

<? break;}
?>
```

Comment: Hi,

I only have the artist / image once in the database. Any ideas why?

Comment: i think the your or clause in the quey is giving you these many rows as it may satisfying the conditions.nevertheless use break itll help you.:)